# AAPT: error: Resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round not found

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.6.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.5.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.5.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\Semh-\Desktop\ateizm_fikri\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:19: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.ateizm_fikri:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
```

Gradle and packages are in the latest version, I still get this error.

Comment: Post your project structure please.

Comment: I found that a line in the androidmanifest file was causing the error.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error log points out to the resource file referenced in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\Semh-\Desktop\ateizm_fikri\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:19: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.ateizm_fikri:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
```

Check the location of `mipmap/ic_launcher_round` and update the manifest file with the correct asset name to solve the error.